# How to display the html page only after loading the whole data of three json files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I parsed three different json files here's my code

```js
    //factory 
    app.factory('myapp', ['$http', 
          function($http) { 
             function getLists() { 
                  var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']; 
                  var list = []; 
                  for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){ 
                     $http.get(tab[i])
                    .then(function(res) { 
                         list.push(res.data); 
                     }); 
                  } 
            return list; 
        } return { 
             getLists: getLists 
         }; 
]);
    //controller
         $scope.list = myapp.getLists();
```

My challenge now is to display this data in the html file once all the data is loaded so the whole table appear without displaying the page if one of the json files is not loaded yet.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
<td>{{d.nm}}</td>
<td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
<td>{{d.hse}}</td>
<td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

I tried the ng-clock but in vain I am using AngularJs 1.3.5

Comment: Could Promise.All be helpful here? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a default class to everything you want to be hidden like this

`body.is-loading { display: none; }`
(or add a spinner/loading indicator, which is probably better as the user gets the information, what's going on)

As soon as you're data is loaded and inserted, i.e. after `list.push(res.data);`, you remove this class. Either via dom manipulation `angular.element(body).removeClass('is-loading')` or by simply setting a $scope/$rootScope variable, which adds/removes this class using `ng-class`:

```
<body ng-class='{"is-loading": isLoading }'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem with my page, the solution I found is to asynchronously bootstrap my angular application. follow this link which help me out.

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data

Hope this will work out for you as well...